# Error: struct Type is not an expression

Tags: struct, go

Using `struct` and a function that is supposed to print out the struct's elements, I have written this simple program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Salutation struct {
    name     string
    greeting string
}

func Greet(salutation Salutation) {
    fmt.Println(salutation.name)
    fmt.Println(salutation.greeting)
}

func main() {
    var s = Salutation
    s.name = "Alex"
    s.greeting = "Hi"
    Greet(s)
}
```

When I run it I get the error `go:16: type Salutation is not an expression`. What goes wrong here?

Interestingly enough, when I change the definition of `s` to `var s = Salutation {"Alex", "Hi"}` it works just fine. But they are basically different syntactic ways to define the same entity. That's why I don't understand the source of the error.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The error is on this line

```
    var s = Salutation
```

The thing to the right of the = must evaluate to a value. `Salutation` is a type, not  value.  Here are three ways to declare s:

```
 var s Salutation      // variable declaration using a type 

 var s = Salutation{}  // variable declaration using a value

 s := Salutation{}     // short variable declaration
```

The result of all three declarations is identical. The third variation is usually preferred to the second, but cannot be used to declare a package-level variable.

See the language specification [for all of the details on variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations).

The variable declaration and field initializations can be combined into a single statement:

```
 var s = Salutation{name: "Alex", greeting: "Hello"} // variable declaration

 s := Salutation{name: "Alex", greeting: "Hello"}    // short variable declaration
```

Comment: `type salution struct{}` is it possible to log  `struct` `fmt.Println(salution,"struct typee")` @Cerise Limon

Comment: I imported a package named 'settings'. Inside settings I have few files, one of these files is only a struct. Why the first example did NOT work but the second one did?

Answer (score 6):

4th way:

**var s *Salutation = &( Salutation{} );**

I always pass structs by reference, not value.
And always pass primitives by value.

Your method re-written as a reciever method:

```
func (s *Salutation) Greet()() {
    fmt.Println(s.name)
    fmt.Println(s.greeting)
}
```

Full Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func NewSalutation()(*Salutation){
    return &( Salutation{} );
}
type Salutation struct {
    name     string
    greeting string
}

func (s *Salutation) Greet()() {
    fmt.Println(s.name)
    fmt.Println(s.greeting)
}

func main() {
    var s *Salutation;   //:<--Null
    s = NewSalutation()  //:<--Points To Instance
    s.name     = "Alex"
    s.greeting = "Hi"
    s.Greet();
}
```